# Touch mice and clicks without mechanical force

Tags: windows, mouse

I'm looking for a mouse with which you can send left and right clicks without having to exert mechanical force in pressing a button. Microsoft seems to be selling three different kinds of 'touch mice' which sound promising, but the reviews are confusing; some claim there are no buttons, some claim there are buttons.

Of the Microsoft Touch Mouse, Arc Touch Mouse and Explorer Touch Mouse, which if any do allow you to make left and right clicks without having to press a mechanical button?

Are there any other differences between the three models?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says the Explorer Touch Mouse is just a tap to click, no left/right buttons, but left/right "zones". So to left click, you tap the left zone, and vice versa. I'm not sure about the others.

EDIT: I looked up the other two above-mentioned mice in Microsoft Store and it appears that they are also tap the left to left click and vice versa.

Comment: And sadly they lied; the useless extra features for making windows dance around the place work with touch, but left and right click don't.